# Hogwarts Legacy Steam Game Not Lauching On Ubuntu 23.10 Nvidia Graphics Card

Tags: nvidia, games, steam

I am running Ubuntu 23.10 and using the Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060 and I cant seem to launch Hogwarts Legacy through steam and proton. I get this error. "Sorry somthing went wrong please visit [https://support.codefusion.technology/pp_inaa2nm/?e=88500006&l=english"](https://support.codefusion.technology/pp_inaa2nm/?e=88500006&l=english%22) And the website doesnt tell me anything. Exact error box

I launched with a lot of proton versions it and I was expecting to see the game run.